# How does DNA resolve on size exclusion resin?

Tags: dna, purification, chromatography

We generally have a good idea of how DNA separates using agarose gel electrophoresis, how well does DNA resolve on a SEC resin like superose? I get the impression that salt influences where it elutes.

Is it possible to compare the molecular weight of DNA and where it elutes to the molecular weight of proteins and peptides and where that elutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works pretty well and can be used to desalt DNA. The DNA runs a bit different than proteins since it is more a long stretched molecule while a lot of proteins are globular. See this references (the first is about the behaviour of DNA on superose):

- [Size-exclusion chromatography of DNA restriction fragments. Fragment
  length determinations and a comparison with the behaviour of proteins
  in size-exclusion chromatography.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2568993)
- [Size exclusion chromatography of DNA and viruses: properties of
  spherical and asymmetric molecules in porous networks](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ma00018a008)
- [Size exclusion chromatography of plasmid DNA isoforms](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021967309010450)